# How to copy data from SQL query analyzer results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am inserting stack trace of exception into table.But When I execute select query for that table from sql query analyzer then I dont see complete stack trace in it.
Here is the code..

```
DataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(
    conn, 
    "usp_insert_error_detail", 
    iproductType, 
    "error", 
    ex.Message.ToString(), 
    ex.StackTrace.ToString());
```

Comment: What is the type of the field that you are inserting the stack trace in to?  It is probably being truncated on insert.  Also, if the parameter definition in your stored procedure is incorrect, that would truncate the value as well.

Comment: Datatype is nvarchar(200) in db and sp both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you said the data type for the stack trace is NVARCHAR(200), this is likely not sufficient.  You need to make it much bigger, since stack traces can easily exceed 200 characters.  You could make it NVARCHAR(MAX), which indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size, in bytes, is two times the number of characters entered + 2 bytes.

Thanks to JSR for the correction, I didn't realize varchar(max) was introduced in SQL 2005.

Comment: Use nvarchar(max) instead of ntext.  The text and ntext datatypes are depreciated.

Comment: I thought varchar(Max) didn't appear until SQL 2008.  Question says 2005

Comment: @MarkSherretta precisely in [SQL2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939(v=sql.90).aspx) was firstly introduced the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` option. And NTEXT is depreciated as JSR already pointed out.